# PHP Ajax returning HTML twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP/Ajax function that returns a list of countries with the given characters in a textbox. Ofcourse Ajax updates this list everytime the textbox gets edited.

Index.PHP calls all the other files, classes and HTML. But when the textbox gets updated, Ajax sends a POST variable to index.PHP because this is where the Search.PHP file with the class name SearchEngine gets called. But because he sends this to the index.php everything keeps getting reloaded and the HTML will be returned twice.

Index.php

```
<?php
require_once("cgi_bin/connection.php");
require_once("Database_Handler.Class.php");
require_once("HTML_Page.Class.php");
require_once("search.php");

$hostname_conn = "localhost";
$database_conn = "ajax";
$username_conn = "root";
$password_conn = "";

$db = new DatabaseHandler();
$conn = $db->openConnection($hostname_conn, $username_conn, $password_conn, $database_conn);

$IndexPage = new page();
echo $IndexPage->render();
$SearchEngine = new SearchEngine($conn); 
?>
```

Please ignore the poor and unsecure database connection. I am currently transforming all my code to PDO and refining it but that is for later.

Search.PHP

```
<?php
class SearchEngine{

    private $html;

    public function __construct($conn){

        $this->html = '<li class="result">
                            <h3>NameReplace</h3>
                            <a target="_blank" href="ULRReplace"></a>
                        </li>';

        if (isset($_POST["query"])) {
            $search_string = $_POST['query'];
        }

        //$search_string = mysql_real_escape_string($search_string);

        if (strlen($search_string) >= 1 && $search_string !== ' ') {

            $query = 'SELECT * FROM country WHERE name LIKE "%' . $search_string . '%"';
            $result = $conn->prepare($query);
            $result->execute();
            $result_array = $result->fetchAll();

                foreach ($result_array as $result) {
                    $display_name = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['name']);
                    $display_url = 'sadf';

                    $output = str_replace('NameReplace', $display_name, $this->html);
                    $output = str_replace('ULRReplace', $display_url, $output);
                    echo($output);
                }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

And as final the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function search() {
    var query_value = $('input#search').val();
    $('b#search-string').html(query_value);

    if(query_value !== ''){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php", //Referring to index.php because this is where the class SearchEngine is called
            data: { query: query_value },
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#results").html(html);
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
}

$("input#search").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    if (search_string == '') {
        $("ul#results").fadeOut();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    }

    else {
        $("ul#results").fadeIn();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
        $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
});
});
```

note: HTML is being returned from the "page" class called inside Index.php

How do i not let everything get called twice?

Thank you,

EDIT: A new file was suggested where i direct the ajax url to AutoComplete.php

AutoComplete.PHP

> Please explain what should be in the file and why. I am clueless.

Comment: Don't send the ajax to index.php from index.php That's like making an infinite loop.

Comment: @developerwjk Well, how would i start to solve this problem? because what you told me is what i already figured out.

Comment: Use different scripts for serving AJAX and page display. Or have your script check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` -- if it's `GET`, it displays the page, if it's `POST` it returns the AJAX response.

Comment: `$(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));` setTimeout for what? i think the database query time is enought

Comment: Make another page to call the search class just for ajax calls.

Comment: Create another file called autocomplete.php for instance there you can put the query to retrieve the results and make your ajax call without any problem

Comment: @Barmar How exactly do you mean different scripts? how would i achieve that since there is always a file calling others right? please bare with me, i am a noob in php with ajax.

Comment: different scripts = new php file :)

Comment: Write a script called `dosearch.php`, and then use `url: "dosearch.php"`.

Comment: @martinezjc Alright i understand what you mean, but i can't think of a way to achieve what you are proposing, could you help me out some more?

Comment: create another file and the change it here `url: "index.php"` to `url: "autocomplete.php"` for example. Move the code that make the query for the results from index to autocomplete :)

Comment: @developerwjk: doesn't matter where you send it to. it can be the same script, with a simple `if($_POST['doajax']) { do ajax stuff } else { show form}` type routing system.

Comment: I am getting to many comments with suggestions and criticism. could somebody please create a "answer" with more details. I understand what you propose but i do not understand what i should write in this document. i can not keep up with all these comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, just add a parameter to your Ajax call to tell the index.php its being called by Ajax, and then wrap an if-statement around the two lines that print out your actual index page:

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['calledByAjax']))
{
  $IndexPage = new page();
  echo $IndexPage->render();
}
```

and in your Ajax call:

```
data: { query: query_value, calledByAjax: 'true'  },
```

Or make another php page, like ajaxsearch.php that's the same as your index.php but lacking those two lines, and call that in your Ajax call.

Comment: Ignore my last comments, that was just a simple mistake by myself. Thank you so much this has worked for me! thank you for having patience with me and explaining to me.

Answer (score 0):

First thing (this is a sample, not tested yet)

**autocomplete.php**

```
<?php
$search_string = $_POST['query'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM country WHERE name LIKE "%' . $search_string . '%"';
$result = $conn->prepare($query);
$result->execute();
$result_array = $result->fetchAll();

foreach ($result_array as $result) {
    $display_name = preg_replace("/" . $search_string . "/i", "<b>" . $search_string . "</b>", $result['name']);
    $display_url = 'sadf';

    $output = str_replace('NameReplace', $display_name, $this->html);
    $output = str_replace('ULRReplace', $display_url, $output);
 }

echo($output);
?>
```

**autocomplete.js**

```
function search() {
var query_value = $('input#search').val();
$('b#search-string').html(query_value);

if(query_value !== ''){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "autocomplete.php", //Here change the script for a separated file
        data: { query: query_value },
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("ul#results").html(html);
        }
    });
}

return false;
}

$("input#search").keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    if (search_string == '') {
        $("ul#results").fadeOut();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $("ul#results").fadeIn();
        $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
        search(); // call the function without setTimeout 
    }
  });
 });
```

Have luck :)

Comment: Alright now what should i do with Search.PHP to me it looks completely useless and i am just altering a few bits of code from that file?

Comment: And how should i call autocomplete since its not a class anymore etc.

Comment: we dont know that you had a search.php file, you just put the index.php file, you must give more details to get a right answer :)

Comment: But.. in my question i stated the name of every file and under the name a block of code with everything inside of it. The block code of autocomplete.php is nearly the same as search.php

Comment: The only file i didnt give was HTML_Page.class.PHP and the Style.css for obvious reasons. since one is almost pure HTML and the other css

Comment: Ok, when you call to search.php? did you try to remove the setTimeout function?

Comment: in Index.PHP. thats what the Ajax url refers to index because i call the class from Index.php. At the very bottom of the file '$SearchEngine = new SearchEngine($conn);'

Comment: And why exactly would i remove the setTimout function?

Comment: setTimeOut make a call every 100 miliseconds to the search function, too many read to the database is a short interval, you can call only to the search function